# Should there be a canonical "How/where do I get package X edge PPA" question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Should there be a canonical "How/where do I get package X edge PPA" question?

Alternately, should it be rolled in to the "What are PPAs and how do I use them" question?

I've seen at least three questions in the last week that could have been answered/duped to:
"This is how you search launchpad..."

I added a couple of CW answers.  Feel free to propose other options.

By edge PPA, I mean a PPA *possibly the official +1 PPA if available* where active development is taking place.

This type of generic answer would be useful for things like the previously repetitive "Where do I get Gimp latest", "Where can I get Unity active development train without upgrading to beta", "Where can I get libsane-perl-xyz for gscan2pdf", or any other "Where can I get package xyz that is not in stable yet".

I think edge PPAs are distinguished from personal project PPAs by the fact that they are already in repo and the OP of a question wants an edge/squeeze/+1 version.

Comment: I dont't think this is a simple as a poll question, while I formulate a response it's really more of a discussion piece about how we want to handle a grey area

Comment: Fair point.  I didn't think it was a proper poll question, I just try and put up some possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be rolled in to the "What are PPAs and how do I use them" question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be a generic  "How/where do I get package X edge PPA" question?

Comment: Does this refer to one general answer, or does this include a list of common edge PPA's?

Comment: One general question answer covering how to search launchpad for a package and navigate.

Comment: OK Creating a new answer as the alternative...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be one question with a generic "How/where do I get package X edge PPA" and a list of commonly-searched-for PPA's.

Answer (score -3):

No, I think we should have loads of questions about "Which PPA should I get this package from?"